# Unattended installation of a .pkg file in Haiku

Tags: command-line, script, packages, unattended, haiku

Is there a way to do this from the command-line, additionally being able to specify the destination partition?

I tried to create an empty partition, and install the package onto that, so I could just zip the results, but PackageInstaller won't install to an empty partition.

I've gotten as far as identifying the destination partition drop down list via `hey` but I don't know how to make it list its elements or select one.

Comment: This question is now deprecated by .hpkg files, which are pretty straightforward to install from the command-line by copying into `~/config/packages`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are only three apps which can read BeOS .pkg files:

PackageBuilder, SoftwareValet and PackageInstaller. AFAIK neither supports command-line interface.

Comment: Hmm...good to know.  Do any of them support `hey`?  If not is there some way to do it anyway?